# Does "walk in" here just mean "enter someplace"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The full text is from the lines of a comedy TV drama:

> Because fathers never really know who their daughters are. They don't want to know, do they?
>
> It would be terrifying to know who they are and what they do, and because they don't really know any of this, sometimes they can just **walk in** unexpectedly,and, suddenly, it's like, "Hey, you're a whore. Who knew?"

My question is, does "walk in" here just mean "enter someplace" like enter his daughter's room and says something...?

Answer (score 2):

In a word: yes. "Walking in on someone" is a common phrase that implies that one or both of them weren't expecting it.